# How to modify a layout of an activity in a service class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-service

There is one activity("MainActivity.java") and its layout file("activity_main.xml"). Now I have a class called "MyService.java" which has extended "Service" and I want to change the backgound of "@+id/service_iv" in "MyService.java" by invoking "onStartCommand" function. How to get the layout or view of "MainActivity.java" in "MyService.java" as a object and modify it? Thanks!

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/service_off_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="turn off"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/service_on_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="turn on"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/service_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/rabbit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

create an interface and call its method in service. Define the interface's  method in main activity and change the image view accordingly.